# Change text of child page from master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I need to change text of header of child page from master page depending upon some logic. Below is my code in master page:

```
<div id="content-header">
    <h1>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphHead" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </h1>
</div>
```

In child page I have below code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphHead" runat="Server">
  TEXT
</asp:Content>
```

How can I change value of TEXT to any other from master page?

Answer (score 1):

You can search controls in the MasterPage. If you set text directly in your ContentPlaceHolder like your example, the text will be in a LiteralControl:

```
((LiteralControl)this.FindControl("cphHead").Controls[0]).Text = "Change TEXT";
```

Or if you want search to a control in the page control collection:

```
ControlCollection controls = this.FindControl("cphHead").Controls;

foreach (Control control in controls)
{
    if (control.GetType() == typeof(LiteralControl))
    {
        ((LiteralControl)control).Text = "Change TEXT";
        break;
    }
}
```